# MVC 4 Successful Login Sometimes Returns to Login Screen

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Every so often, when someone logs into my ASP.Net MVC 4 application, they are returned to the login screen.  Re-entering credentials always allows for a successful login.  Logging confirms that correct credentials were entered on both attempts.

The login code looks like

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    try
    {
        MyData md = (MyData)Session["MyData"]; // Should be null, but testing that it is after logging out and back in

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                logger.Info("Successful login '" + model.UserName + "' from IP " + Request.IPAddresses());
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                    && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                logger.Warn("Login failed '" + model.UserName + "' from IP " + Request.IPAddresses());
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            logger.Warn("Login failed (model state invalid) '" + model.UserName + "' from IP " + Request.IPAddresses());
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form.
        logger.Warn("Something failed during login.  Redisplaying login form.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Warn("Exception during logon process: " + ex.Message);
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

The variable *logger* is an the default NLog class logger.

Immediately after reproducing the issue in an isolated environment, the log file looks like

> 2012-08-22 10:51:25.4581 INFO Successful login 'demo' from IP 10.0.0.21
>
> 2012-08-22 10:51:39.9741 INFO Successful login 'demo' from IP 10.0.0.21

None of the warning log entries that would indicate a failed login or Exception are present in the log file.

This seems to happen with greater frequency when the web server has been idle for some time.

How can I diagnose/resolve the issue?

Comment: It sounds like you're calling `return Redirect(returnUrl);` where `returnUrl` is the login page.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I'm quite certain that the URL entered in the browser was just `http://localhost`.  Any idea how I could get to the code path where *returnUrl* ends up being the login page?  I'll add logging for that case in any event.

Comment: Could you log your returnUrl on succsesful login and reproduce bug?

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov: I added that logging, but the bug has not recurred yet.